# How to differentiate between two local notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have two local notifications, one that triggers based on date and the other one based on time.

When they are triggered the `didReceive` delegate is called with the `UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier` identifier:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
        print("Dismiss Action")
    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
        // this part is called when notification is triggered
    ......................................
    default:
        print("Unknown action")
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

Is there a way inside this delegate to differentiate between the two notifications ?

I want different actions based on what notifications was triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **response** is a [`UNNotificationResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationresponse). It has two immutable properties:

- `actionIdentifier`, a `String` which is correlates to the categories you've added to userNotificationCenter
- `notification` which is a `UNNotification` which contains the
  original **request** ie it's an instance of [`UNNotificationRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotification/1649324-request).

So switch using: `response.notification.request.identifier`

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
response.notification.request.identifier
```

the `UNNotificationRequest` have the identifier, as is show in `UNNotificationRequest.h`

Hope this helps